# How to use the while loop and how to use the count in the loop in sql server

Tags: sql-server, loops, t-sql

My query:

```
Declare @counter int
set @counter = 1 
while @counter <= 12
Begin update table_1
set count = @counter
set @counter = @counter + 1

end
```

I'm using this query and I'm expecting my table have 12 records in that column (1-12),but after I run the query, nothing show up in my existing table. Can anyone tell me how to deal with this?

Comment: Looks like you need to change your update to insert instead.

Comment: As Robert wrote in his comment, you seem to be using `update` when you actually need to be using `insert`. This is very basic stuff in SQL - any online SQL tutorial will probably have a somewhat decent explanation on different DML statements. You should probably read that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use recursive `CTE` :

```
with cte as (
     select 1 as cnt
     union all
     select cnt + 1
     from cte c
     where c.cnt < 12
)
insert into table_1 (count)
   select c.cnt
   from cte c;
```

If you have more count then use `MAX Recursion` Hint, recursive cte has default 100 recursive.

```
insert into table_1 (count)
  select c.cnt
  from cte c
  option(maxrecursion 0);
```